# Kubernetes Persistant Volume overwrites image data

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod that reads from an image that contains data within `var/www/html`.  I want this data to be stored in a persistent volume.  This is my deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: app
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            container: app
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                container: app
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: app
                  image: my/toolkit-app:working
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 80
                  volumeMounts:
                      - mountPath: /var/www/html
                        name: toolkit-volume
                        subPath: html
            volumes:
                - name: toolkit-volume
                  persistentVolumeClaim:
                      claimName: azurefile
            imagePullSecrets:
                - name: my-cred
```

However when I look into the pod I can see the directory is empty:

[image: Empty directory]

If I comment out the persistent volume:

```
              #volumeMounts:
              #    - mountPath: /var/www/html
              #      name: toolkit-volume
              #      subPath: html
```

I can see that the image data is there:

[image: Non-empty directory]

So it seems like the persistent volume is overwriting the existing directory - is there a way round this? Ideally I want `/var/www/html` to be stored in a separate volume and for any existing files within the image to be stored there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a problem of visibility: If you mount an empty volume at a specific path, you won't be able to see, what was placed there in the container image.

From your question I assume that you want to be able to rollout updates by the means of a new container image, but at the same time retain variable data, that was created at the same directory from your application.

You could achieve this with the following method:
Use an init container with the same image and mount your persistent directory to a different path, for example `/data`
As command for the init container copy the contents of `/var/www/html` to `/data`.

In the regular container image use the mount you already have, it will contain your variable data and the updated data from the init container.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes total sense - I'm new to Kubernetes so pennies are still dropping left right and center - thanks

Comment: when i use NFS ,The files in the container will automatically appear in the empty pvc. Is this related to the underlying storage implementation?